# События в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, события

Здравствуйте!
Есть задача, подписаться на события генерируемые сторонней библиотекой.
Библиотека подключена в References.

В десктопном приложении всё работает отлично:

```
public class TEvents3 : TEvents
{

    public static TEvents3 Instance
    {
        get { return new TEvents3(); }
    }

}    

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var t = TEvents3.Instance;
}
```

События срабатывают.

Всё тоже самое делаю в WEB. события не срабатывают.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   var t = TEvents3.Instance;
}
```

Есть подозрения что события в WEB имеют какую то специфику.
Знающие люди подскажите, что я делаю не так и почему события не срабатывают?

Comment: Я не вижу тут подписку на события, непонятно, что должно происходить при срабатывании события (как вы поняли, что события не срабатывают?), а статический Instance каждый раз возвращает новый экземпляр класса, что как то странно.

Comment: Я не стал приводить весь год, думаю это лишнее. Подписка на события реализована в TEvents, Сравнивал десктоп и  web под дебаггером. Вопрос не в правильности реализации событий как таковых, они реализованы верно. А в том почему (из-за чего) тот же самый код не работает в WEB ? И почему каждый раз?  там и там Instance вызывается один раз.

Comment: Какой ответ вы хотите получить, если не показали код, который работает не так, как вы ожидаете? Естественно, есть разница между десктоп и веб приложением. Веб приложение может засыпать или рестартиться само, в вебе совсем другая модель управления состоянием и работа с юзер интерфейсом. То, что вы показали, драматично недостаточно не то что для ответа, но и для понимания сути вопроса. Предоставьте минимально работающий пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve только после этого имеет смысл что то думать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   var t = TEvents3.Instance;
}
```

`var t` умирает как только Application_Start завершает работу, и нечему реагировать на события